# Send a custom WooCommerce email when custom order change

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, email

I am facing a problem to send a custom email when order status changes.

I created a *custom WooCommerce email*  'WC_Ready_To_Ship_`Email' and a *custom WooCommerce order* 'wc-ready-to-ship'.

What I am trying to achieve is when the status order changes to 'ready to ship', an email will be sent to the customer.

Here is my code in my plugin file

```php
function plugin_init () {
  if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
    // Register new order status to woocommerce
    add_action( 'init', 'plugin_register_custom_status' );
    // Add new order status to woocommerce
    add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'plugin_add_status' );
    // Create custom email for woocommerce
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_classes', 'add_ready_to_ship_woocommerce_emails' );
  }
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'plugin_init');

// Create custom email for woocommerce
function add_ready_to_ship_woocommerce_emails( $email_classes ) {
  require( 'includes/class-wc-ready-to-ship-email.php' );
  $email_classes['WC_Ready_To_Ship_Email'] = new WC_Ready_To_Ship_Email();
  return $email_classes;
}
```

and here is the `class-wc-ready-to-ship-email.php` file

```php
class WC_Ready_To_Ship_Email extends WC_Email {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->id = 'wc_ready_to_ship_email';
        $this->customer_email = true;
        $this->title = 'Ready to ship';
        $this->description = '';

       $this->heading = 'Order Status';
       $this->subject = 'Ready to ship';

       $this->template_html  = 'emails/wc-customer-ready-to-ship.php';
       $this->template_plain = 'emails/plain/wc-customer-ready-to-ship.php';
       $this->template_base  = PLUGIN_PATH . 'templates/';
       $this->placeholders   = array(
            '{order_date}'   => '',
            '{order_number}' => '',
        );
       // Trigger on new paid orders
       add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_ready-to-ship', array( $this, 'trigger', 10, 2 ) );
       parent::__construct();
  }

  public function trigger( $order_id, $order = false ) {
        $this->setup_locale();

        if ( $order_id && ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
            $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        }

        if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
            $this->object                         = $order;
            $this->recipient                      = $this->object->get_billing_email();
            $this->placeholders['{order_date}']   = wc_format_datetime( $this->object->get_date_created() );
            $this->placeholders['{order_number}'] = $this->object->get_order_number();
        }

        if ( $this->is_enabled() && $this->get_recipient() ) {
            $this->send( $this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments() );
        }

        $this->restore_locale();
  }

  public function get_content_html() {
      return wc_get_template_html( $this->template_html, array(
            'order'              => $this->object,
            'email_heading'      => $this->get_heading(),
            'sent_to_admin'      => false,
            'plain_text'         => false,
            'email'              => $this,
        ), '', $this->template_base );
  }

  public function get_content_plain() {
    return wc_get_template_html( $this->template_plain, array(
            'order'              => $this->object,
            'email_heading'      => $this->get_heading(),
            'sent_to_admin'      => false,
            'plain_text'         => true,
            'email'              => $this,
        ), '', $this->template_base );
  }

} // end WC_Ready_To_Ship_Email class
```

Everything seems to be OK on WooCommerce -> Settings -> Emails and there is no error in log files.

Can you help me to find a way to send the email, please!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need do two changes:

1. Add a filter to `woocommerce_email_actions` that adds the action hook which should trigger the notification:

```php
function add_ready_to_ship_woocommerce_email_action( $email_actions ) {
  $email_actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_ready-to-ship';
  return $email_actions;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'add_ready_to_ship_woocommerce_email_action' );
```

2. Change the trigger hook in the email class (add a `_notification` suffix):

```php
// Trigger on new paid orders
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_ready-to-ship_notification', array( $this, 'trigger', 10, 2 ) );
```